# What's the side effect of the following macro in C ? Embedded C

Tags: c, macros

```
#define MIN(A,B) ((A) <=  (B) ? (A) : (B))
```

this is the macro , I was asked what's the side effect if I used the following :

```
least = MIN(*p++, b);
```

**Note: This was embedded c question**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It evaluates `p++` twice. Also, since the first evaluation changes `p`, the second time around **it will point to a different element**. So the returned value will be `*(initialp + 1)` or `b`.

You should try it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

The macro will expand to:

```
least = ((*p++)<=(b)?(*p++):(b))
```

you will have then `*p++` twice in your statement (i.e., it will be incremented twice).

Comment: Just a comment not completely related to the question: this is one of the reasons why many languages don't have macros: the can obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 2):

`*p++` gets evaluated twice as the macro expands to `*p++ <= b ? *p++ : b`

Also, there is no such thing as "embedded C".

Answer (score 1):

Assume initial address of p = 0xfcf0, *p = 1, b = 2, value @ 0xfcf4 = 5 and value @ 0xfcf8 = 15

The macro will expand as

least = ((*p++) <= (b) ? (*p++) : (b));

i.e least = ((1) <= (2) ? (*p++) : (b));

since *p is incremented twice.

1)  *p++ --> now p will point to address 0xfcf4;

2)  *p++ --> now p will point to address 0xfcf8;

So least = 15; (the values in the address 0xfcf8). Hope it helps.