# whats the output?

Tags: c, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the side effect of the following macro in C ? Embedded C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299286/whats-the-side-effect-of-the-following-macro-in-c-embedded-c)

What will be the output for the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAN(x,y) ((x) < (y))?(x):(y)
main()
{  
    int i=10,j=5,k=0;
    k= MAN(i++,++j);
    printf("%d %d %d" ,i,j,k);
}
```

Here i thought that MAN(10,6) will be called and the output will be:

```
11 6 6
```

However the output is

```
11 7 7
```

Can some one please explain this.

Comment: @chris That's unrelated. We're not adding anything here or assigning `x = x++`.

Comment: @Xeo It's *not* the same thing. OP's code is basically `if( i++ > ++j ) { k = ++j; }`. The sequence is well-defined.

Comment: Never mind. I forgot there's a sequence point in there. *The ﬁrst operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
evaluation of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated). The second operand
is evaluated only if the ﬁrst compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
the ﬁrst compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand
(whichever is evaluated), converted to the type described below.
110)*

Comment: @Juhana: Yep, nvm, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember how macros work.. they replace the text exactly as it is, and do not evaluate their arguements as you would expect functions to do.

```
k= MAN(i++,++j);
```

Is actually

```
k= ((i++) < (++j))?(i++):(++j)
```

This is why `j` is incremented twice.

Comment: +1... I so hate the feeling of knowing the answer, but being slower to type :)

Comment: @ppeterka has happened to me as well several times.

Comment: I'm sure - seeing your rep. It's just a dumb human thing that feeling bad about being slower supersedes feeling 'hey, at least I knew the correct answer to that' :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply sub: x <- i++, y <- ++j into your macro define, then you can see that

```
((i++) < (++j))?(i++):(++j)
```

i++ and ++j are both executed when doing the comparison; since the comparison returns false, ++j would be executed therefore you got the result

Answer (score 0):

it becomes

i++ < ++j ? i++ : ++j

i will not be less than j,   so we use the second argument

so we do a i++ and ++j   and another ++j

so 10 + 1  =11    5 + 1 + 1  = 7   and return the second argument..... 7

11 7 7

Comment: Just looked it up, you're right. Harm undone.

Answer (score 0):

Since MAN is a *macro* and not a function, this code:

```
k = MAN(i++,++j);
```

Means this:

```
k = ((i++) < (++j))?(i++):(++j)
```

So, `j` gets incremented twice: once in the `<` test, and again when `(++j)` is evaluated. If `MAN` were a *function* and not a macro, the incremented *values* would be passed, not the expressions themselves, and your answer would be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In macros the it does not calculate the value and pass it just replace the symbol so it becomes some thing like this

```
MAN(i++,++j) ((i++) < (++j))?(i++):(++j)
```

so here ++j executes twice and the answer becomes 11,7,7